# How are different wavelength components collected by the same detector in a spectrometer?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection, spectroscopy, frequency

Let's think, we have a detector array (128x1 and each CMOS detector responds 400 to 1000 nm TSL1401CL that way, each detector has 4.6875 nm interval). Then, basically in a spectrometer a prism reflect the waves (visible and near-ir) after that, these reflected waves come to the detector array. I understand that. But I don't understand that how each reflected waves comes to the always same detector.(for instance 400 nm is on 1st one than 405 nm on 2nd one...). What kind of optical system assure it?

Comment: Isn't the optical system that ensure's this the *prism?*

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE. In general you will find more success if the titles of your questions are as specific as possible. I've edited it for you to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

The prism doesn't reflect light, it refracts the light.  Different wavelengths will be refracted (bent) by different amounts.  In the visible spectrum, this will produce the familiar rainbow pattern we're all familiar with.  If you direct the refracted light at a linear detector, each pixel of the detector will measure the optical power at a different wavelength.

Comment: I understand that. Does 'linear' mean every pixel just responds certain wavelength? After waves reflected even light source changes each pixel has certain wavelength?( I mean with white led 2. pixel has 450 nm and with orange one again 450 or almost same?)

Comment: @VeyselBekirMacit: A simple CMOS array without built in color filters responds to a whole range of frequencies. It's basically a black and white camera. If you want to detect colors, like in digital cameras, you need to place filters in front of the pixels, which is what camera manufacturers do. In a spectrometer there is no filter but either a prism or a grating which disperses the light from a thin slit across the surface of the chip. The detection of each photon, however, is independent of the wavelength.

Answer (score 1):

Most commercial spectrometers use gratings rather than prisms, but that's a side issue.

To answer your main question:  the optics inside a spectrometer re-image the entrance slit onto the detector elements.  In the case of your 1x128 detector, the entrance "slit" is really a small hole which is optically matched to a single pixel in the image plane.  The prism or grating splits the light so the image of the entrance hole, for each wavelength sub-range, is directed to a given pixel.

Other spectrometers use a 2-D array (e.g. 128x128 pixels), allowing you to collect a "slice" image which is 1x128 pixels for each wavelength. The concepts and the reimaging optics are essentially the same.

One model I happen to be familiar with is [this Headwall unit](http://www.headwallphotonics.com/Portals/145999/docs/ds_high%20efficiency%20hyperspec%20nir%20swir_2014.pdf) . The pdf I linked to has some nice schematics of the internal optics.